# How to restrict access to users and groups using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an application which uses application permissions (access without a user) to access these types of resources with Microsoft Graph API:

- [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

As I understand at least `User.Read.All` permission is required, but this will allow access to all the users and I need to restrict access only to specific set of users/groups which will be using the app. How is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Microsoft Graph App Only Permissions be restricted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151694/can-microsoft-graph-app-only-permissions-be-restricted)

Comment: Answer to your referenced question is not satisfiable.